# WPF languages resource selection combo-box not working as it should do

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm working in a WPF C# application that has a ComboBox with 2 language selection. I have found a tutorial online that do exactly what I want in term of changing language resource, but the problem is that I have Several WPF windows and all of them have a button link to the main Window that launched when application is fired where the ComboBox is available. The language selection is working fine when first launched defaulted to English, but the problem arise when you navigate from the main window to another window using different language and when clicked on Home button the language selected is always English although I have changed it to a different language and if I need to to change back to English I need to click on the other language then click back on English to revert to English:
How can make the application detect the current resource dictionary automatically and change the combobox to reflect the selected language? 
here is some of the code:

```
private void ddlLanguage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  
{  
    var currentResourceDictionary = (
        from d in BaseModel.Instance.ImportCatalog.ResourceDictionaryList  
        where d.Metadata.ContainsKey("Culture") && d.Metadata["Culture"].ToString().Equals(vm.SelectedLanguage.Code)  
        select d).FirstOrDefault();

    if (currentResourceDictionary != null)  
    {  
        var previousResourceDictionary = (
            from d in BaseModel.Instance.ImportCatalog.ResourceDictionaryList  
            where d.Metadata.ContainsKey("Culture") && d.Metadata["Culture"].ToString().Equals(vm.PreviousLanguage.Code)  
            select d).FirstOrDefault();

        if (previousResourceDictionary != null && previousResourceDictionary != currentResourceDictionary)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(previousResourceDictionary.Value);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(currentResourceDictionary.Value);

            CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(vm.SelectedLanguage.Code);

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

            Application.Current.MainWindow.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);

            vm.PreviousLanguage = vm.SelectedLanguage;
        }
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel constructor :

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    LoadResources();
    SelectedLanguage = LanguageList.FirstOrDefault();
    PreviousLanguage = SelectedLanguage;
}

private void LoadResources()
{
    LanguageList = new List<Languages>();
    LanguageList.Add(new Languages() { Code = "en-GB", Name = "English" });
    LanguageList.Add(new Languages() { Code = "cy-GB", Name = "Cymraeg" });
}
```

In the MainWindow constructor:

```
MainViewModel vm;  

public MainMenu()  
{  
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

In the MainWindow xaml for the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ddlLanguage" 
          FontSize="22"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageList}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectionChanged"
          Margin="178,61,940,148" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found away that may look unusual to solve my issue: I have initiated the language list from the ViewModel main method and have removed the initiation of the ComboBox and that has left my with a blank entry:

```
public TestViewModel()
{
    language = new List<Languages>
    {
        new Languages { Name="English", Code="en-GB" },
        new Languages { Name="Welsh", Code="cy-GB" },
    };
    //SelectedLanguage = language.FirstOrDefault();
    //PreviousLanguage = selectedLanguage;
}
```

In my `ddlLanguage_SelectionChanged` method I do the following (it may not be robust coding but it has worked for now):

```
private void ddlLanguage_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    #region Method body
    var indx = ddlLanguage.ItemsSource;
    string previousLang = "";

    foreach (var item in indx)
    {
        switch (ddlLanguage.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                ddlLanguage.SelectedItem = "English";
                vm.SelectedLanguage.Code = "en-GB";
                previousLang = "cy-GB";

                var currentResourceDictionary = (
                    from d in BaseModel.Instance.ImportCatalog.ResourceDictionaryList
                    where d.Metadata.ContainsKey("Culture") && d.Metadata["Culture"].ToString().Equals(vm.SelectedLanguage.Code)
                    select d).SingleOrDefault();

                if (currentResourceDictionary != null)
                {
                    var previousResourceDictionaryE = (
                        from d in BaseModel.Instance.ImportCatalog.ResourceDictionaryList
                        where d.Metadata.ContainsKey("Culture") && d.Metadata["Culture"].ToString().Equals(previousLang)
                        select d).SingleOrDefault();

                    if (previousResourceDictionaryE != null && previousResourceDictionaryE != currentResourceDictionary)
                    {
                        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(currentResourceDictionary.Value);
                        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(vm.SelectedLanguage.Code);
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                        Application.Current.MainWindow.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
                        previousLang = vm.SelectedLanguage.Code;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                ddlLanguage.SelectedItem = "Welsh";

                vm.SelectedLanguage.Code = "cy-GB";
                previousLang = "en-GB";
                var currentResourceDictionaryE = (
                    from d in BaseModel.Instance.ImportCatalog.ResourceDictionaryList
                    where d.Metadata.ContainsKey("Culture") && d.Metadata["Culture"].ToString().Equals(vm.SelectedLanguage.Code)
                    select d).SingleOrDefault();
                if (currentResourceDictionaryE != null)
                {
                    if (currentResourceDictionaryE != null)
                    {
                        var previousResourceDictionaryE = (
                            from d in BaseModel.Instance.ImportCatalog.ResourceDictionaryList
                            where d.Metadata.ContainsKey("Culture") && d.Metadata["Culture"].ToString().Equals(previousLang)
                            select d).SingleOrDefault();

                        if (previousResourceDictionaryE != null && previousResourceDictionaryE != currentResourceDictionaryE)
                        {
                            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(currentResourceDictionaryE.Value);
                            CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(vm.SelectedLanguage.Code);
                            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                            Application.Current.MainWindow.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
                            previousLang = vm.SelectedLanguage.Code;
                        }
                    }
                }    
                break;
            }
        }

        #endregion Method body
    }
}
```

This way when application first loaded the ComboBox showing no entry but you will be able to select a chosen language and when clicking back to the main page of application same process start that way the user is not confused on current displayed language and the selected value of the ComboBox which was always referring to `FirstOrDefault()` value.
I managed to use ComboBox property called `ItemSource` and it was index based then use switch statement to apply my logic.

Please feel free to comment if you see any modification I could apply.

Answer (score 0):

First Try to save the selected language in settings or database 
and when the application start change the language using the saved selected language,and put a note tells : must restart the application to apply changes 
. And check that you use DynamicResource in binding like that

```
 <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource myText}"/>
```

Comment: the issue is the view model will always set the selected language to English when i navigate away to a different page with other language selected but when click hone button the other language still displayed but the Selected item in combo display English